# Telescope Equation: wrong understanding?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

It's well known that the basic formula for the angular magnification of an optical telescope is

$$ |M| = \frac{f_{ob}}{f_{oc}} $$

where $f_{ob}$ is the focal length of the objective, and $f_{oc}$ is that of the ocular (the *eye-piece*).

So, if $f_{ob}$ of the objective increases, so will $M$ of the telescope. Now, based on simple lens maker's formula of thin lens approximation,

$$ \frac{1}{f} = (n-1) \left( \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}  \right)$$
a long focal length lens, has a large radius of curvature; i.e., a less curved surface with less bending of incoming light rays.

My question is, assuming every approximation holds, to get larger and larger $M$, we need flatter and flatter objective lenses, so in the limit does that mean that a flat glass, of (practically) infinite radius of curvature, yields
infinite (very large) magnification? And further, since a piece of flat glass can be replaced with empty space (as it won't bend any light rays), could we then, in principle, get an infinite (very large) magnification by just the ocular alone?

What's wrong in this reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of problems:

1. Your formula assumes the telescope is short compared to the distance to the object you're imaging. An infinitely long telescope violates that assumption.

But more seriously:

2. You're using a ray optics approximation, ignoring diffraction. With diffraction, what happens as you increase the focal length without increasing the lens diameter is that you magnify the blur due to diffraction in the same proportion that you magnify the image. So, your infinite telescope is infinitely blurry. You can fix this (in theory) by increasing the lens diameter in proportion to the focal length, but then it's not a flat lens.

Comment: Well, the two answers take "infinity" a little more seriously than I thought they would do for a physical approximation to "very large" quantitiy. I used it in the sense like Sun is at infinity for any practical lense, etc. So apart from diffraction etc, I understand that indeed a practically flat "looking" objective is required for very large M (say for example M = 1E6) with foc = 1mm, that means fob = 1 km...

Comment: @Fat32 True, but you can't practically ignore diffraction.

Comment: Well thanks, as I understand, the objective indeed becomes flatter up to "practical" limits.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the ray diagram of an astronomical telescope.

[image]

with the angular magnification $M = \dfrac \beta \alpha= \dfrac {f_{\rm o}}{f_{\rm e}}$.

Yes, you do get increased magnification as $f_{\rm o}$ gets larger but you also notice that at the same time the telescope gets longer because the intermediate image has to be in the focal plane of the eyepiece.

Moving on to your idea of making the objective lens flatter and flatter.
That requires the eyepiece to be further and further away from the objective and you will note that with a piece of flat glass you run into problems relating to infinite distances etc.

The eyepiece alone will act just like a very short focal length objective lens producing a relatively small image in its focal plane which defeats the purpose of a telescope.

Comment: thanks, I know that it becomes a (n infinteley) longer telescope, so there's nothing wrong in my reasoning? What about the second part: replacing the flat objective with empty space? effectively degenerating the telescope into a single lens device in the limit. for example, can we make a telescope using Earth's atmospehere as objective lens?

Comment: Well thanks, as I understand, the objective indeed becomes flatter up to practical limits...